# How to integrate OpenMPI (or other) with CLion on Intel Mac?

Tags: macos, mpi, clion, openmpi

Recently I tried to integrate OpenMPI with CLion IDE on Intel Mac. I installed Open MPI with

`brew install openmpi`

Now as I see I have to make some changes in CMakeLists.txt in order for this to work, but I don't know what explicitly I shall do. Also if you are comfortable with different mpi (for example mpich) that would be appreciated too! Thanks in advance!

Basic example I'd like to work

```
#include <mpi.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
  int rank, size;

  MPI_Init(&argc, &argv);
  MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &rank);
  MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &size);
  printf("Process #%d of %d\n", rank, size);
  MPI_Finalize();
  return 0;}
```

Comment: see https://www.onooks.com/how-to-import-openmp-and-mpi-to-a-large-clion-cmake-project/

Comment: for curious ones: solution for Apple M1 macs https://betterprogramming.pub/integrating-open-mpi-with-clion-on-apple-m1-76b7815c27f2

Comment: fwiw, this solution is not specific to M1 and should work with Intel processors too

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure whether this answer makes you happy or not, as I don't use `brew` for `MPI` and `GNU` toolchain installation.

I always install them separately, from the sources.

https://www.owsiak.org/building-opencoarrays-on-macos-everything-from-the-sources-gcc-13-2-0/

(it is also a good idea to use `modules` inside `CLI`: https://www.owsiak.org/modules-as-a-convenient-way-of-choosing-build-chain-on-macos/)

Once you have that. You can simply point `CLion` at your installation like so

[image]

and then, you can use `CLion` to build, run, and debug the code

[image]